# Javascript fast prototypal inheritance?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript, and I've found its prototypal inheritance WAY too verbose. So I searched a bit for alternatives, but everything I found used closures and degraded performance significantly because of that.

I tried writing my own and it seems to work. Maybe I misunderstood something, or maybe this is regarded as bad practice for some reason. Can someone with a bit more experience share his thoughts about this approach?

```
var Class = {
  constructor: function() {},
  extend: function(properties) {
    var base = this.prototype || Class;
    var constructor = properties.hasOwnProperty('constructor') ?
      properties.constructor : base.constructor;
    constructor.base = base;
    constructor.prototype = Object.create(base);
    constructor.extend = Class.extend;
    for(var p in properties) {
      constructor.prototype[p] = properties[p];
    }
    constructor.prototype.constructor = constructor;
    return constructor;
  }
};
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xNGAB/

Performance: http://jsperf.com/object-construction99/2

*EDIT:* One thing I still find clumsy is the calls to base class functions, such as `C.base.constructor.call(this);`. I don't really understand why `this` doesn't get properly bound when we do `C.base.constructor()`.

Comment: For one, `Object.create()` requires at least IE9, FF4 and Safari 5 unless you use a shim to implement it.

Comment: `Object.create()` is the way to go with JS and a prototypal approach.

Comment: That seems to be ok? The shim is very straightforward (empty function, set prototype, then instantiate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). It has Ruby-like syntax and compiles into JavaScript. The best part is you can implement prototype inheritance like this (from their user manual):

```
class Animal
  constructor: (@name) ->

  move: (meters) ->
    alert @name + " moved #{meters}m."

class Snake extends Animal
  move: ->
    alert "Slithering..."
    super 5

class Horse extends Animal
  move: ->
    alert "Galloping..."
    super 45

sam = new Snake "Sammy the Python"
tom = new Horse "Tommy the Palomino"
```

Comment: One of the most ugly languages imo :)

Comment: Haha, different strokes for different folks. Pop across to the website and you'll see the fantastic JavaScript that is compiled from this and might think again. It saves a lot of writing, especially when involving prototype inheritance.

Comment: I will, thanks for the hint, doesn't answer my question though :-)

Comment: That's because you have a good method :) CoffeeScript just makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered but just to give another perspective for a micro object-oriented framework for javascript, here:

https://github.com/foo123/classy.js

It also has support for `sweet.js` macros (and es5/es6 advanced features) resulting in an OOP syntactic sugar similar to Java or PHP, both as syntax and as functionality

PS. I am the author

[performance tests on jsperf](http://jsperf.com/fun-with-method-overrides-3/9) for classy.js (and similar approaches e.g @ejohn's object-oriented approach)

Comment: 'i' is not important, \/